# Image following a head

Tags: image, tracking

I have footage of a person moving around and turning their head. I would like to have a 2d image follow the basic shape of their head. Is this possible? I also need the image to grow larger as the head gets closer to the camera.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55826/1853 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/how-do-i-overlay-a-photo-of-a-face-over-a-character-on-a-video/36680#36680

Comment: Yes. There are many ways to do this. If just an outline of the head is needed, you can use a curve object with shape keys. Otherwise if stretching a planar image you can subdivide the plane and, again, use shape keys. Using a lattice to deform it is another way.

Comment: you can also use a plane track technique: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65007/overlaying-an-image-to-cover-a-face-in-a-video/65017#65017 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53933/how-do-i-use-live-motion-and-paste-a-model-onto-it-like-gollum/53955#53955